# QR Code font style is rendering each character as a qr code instead of the text as a whole

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Using xsl I'm trying to render some html text into a Qr Code using a font face. The font renders but it renders each character instead of the whole text into a single Qr Code.
I've tried turning the text into a xsl number variable and trying to render that way

```
<xsl:variable name="OrderNumber" select="number(//Order/Number)" />
<font face="QR font tfb" style="font-size:36pt;"><xsl:value-of select="$OrderNumber"/></font>
```

I'm just trying to take an order number right now and turn it into a scannable qr code. Google and stackoverflow searches are not turning up anything for me.

Comment: Which XSLT version is that, or which XSLT version does the processor support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font you mention is simply a "font" that maps characters to a QR code for that simple character. So you pass [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) ... it does not nor will ever give you a single QR code for a phrase, it gives you a single QR code for each character in the phrase (as a font should do).

You need to implement something other than fonts (like a QR code service).

See https://www.dafont.com/qr-font-tfb.font and you even see each character is a QR code. It is essentially worthless unless you want to QR encode the letter "A".

If you want something to encode phrases or links then something like https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/ would work. There are many others. Google charts has a deprecated one but still works:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=www.mysite.com

Yields:

[image]

So assuming your XSL variable is working, do not use `<font>` and instead use something like `<img>` and build the `src` attribute like the google chart example.

```
<xsl:variable name="OrderNumber" select="number(//Order/Number)" />
<xsl:variable name="chartQR">
   <xsl:text>https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&amp;cht=qr&amp;chl=</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="$OrderNumber"/>
</xsl:variable>
<ing src="{$chartQR}"/>
```

Comment: <img src="{$chartQR}"/>